# My code wont alert if the weight is too large or too small

Tags: html, bbedit

After I get the weight I want the alert to be either "too large" or "too small" depending on the number The prompted user puts in. I can get the code to ask for a weight but after that nothing else alerts.

```
function calculateWeightInNewtons(mass) {

weight = mass * 9.8;
return weight;

if (weight > 500){
    alert("Weight is too big");
}
if (weight < 100){
    alert("weight is too small");
}



}

var massInKilograms = parseFloat(prompt("What is the object's mass in kilograms? "));
calculateWeightInNewtons(massInKilograms);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're returning from the function. The code below that isn't executed. If you need to return a value, make sure you do that after alerting the messages. But ideally, for a function to be cleaner it should only do one thing. So it's best to break down the functionality in different functions.

```js
function calculateWeightInNewtons(mass) {
  weight = mass * 9.8;
  return weight;
}

function alertWeight(weight) {
  if (weight > 500){
      alert("Weight is too big");
  }
  if (weight < 100){
      alert("weight is too small");
  }
}

var massInKilograms = parseFloat(prompt("What is the object's mass in kilograms? "));
var weight = calculateWeightInNewtons(massInKilograms);
alertWeight(weight);
```

Comment: Ohh, i was returning from the function, I think i grasp it now. thank you